# android issue calling glide from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-glide

I am using Glide library for image loading in my android app.

But when i tried to display image using glide in one of my fragment. Its giving me error.

I tried something like

When I comment this line, app works fine.

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    Glide.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/vsjBeMPZtyB7yNsYY56XYxifaQZ.jpg").into((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.movie_image));
    ...
    }
```

And below is the error I am getting

```
04-08 11:04:33.318  26983-26983/com.alpha.popularmoviesi D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM --------- beginning of crash
04-08 11:04:33.320  26983-26983/com.alpha.popularmoviesi E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.alpha.popularmoviesi, PID: 26983
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.alpha.popularmoviesi/com.alpha.popularmoviesi.MovieDetails}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
```

Comment: post your xml code

Comment: post more from your stack trace and also post your `Fragment` lifecycle callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Your xml is wrong.Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment.